# Automatically generate resource keys for localisation in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, localization

I have a large website that I have to localise. To do that, I make use of UI cultures and .resx files. But the controls on the site do not have the `meta:resourcekey` value necessary to refer to them in the resource files. I'd like to generate them automatically, using the element IDs as the keys, so that this:

```
<ext:Window ID="wndLoginWindow" Hidden="true">
</ext:Window>
```

Becomes this:

```
<ext:Window ID="wndLoginWindow" Hidden="true" meta:resourcekey="wndLoginWindow">
</ext:Window>
```

Is there a Visual Studio tool/plugin to do this? Do I have to resort to regex substitution? Or is there another way to localise the website that's not as manual to implement?

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2010 has a `Generate Local Resource` option under the `Tools` menu. The cursor may have to be actively in the content area for the menu option to be available. I've been using this to create resource files and it automatically adds the resource key attribute to my controls. It works with Literals and Labels and the like but might not work for more complex controls (my pages are pretty simple so I haven't run up against that).

Comment: Cool features for 2010.